# convert value in txt file to object json

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
[2023-01-28 17:54:59]Name John, Cart Iphone13
[2023-01-28 17:54:59]Name John, Cart Iphone14
[2023-01-28 17:54:59]Name John, Cart Iphone15
[2023-01-28 17:54:59]Name John, Cart Iphone16
[2023-01-28 18:24:29]Name Frank, Cart Android10
[2023-01-28 18:24:29]Name Frank, Cart Android11
```

I have data in .txt file like this. how convert to object JSON and groupBy same date and name in javascript? I need result like this

```js
[
    {
        "date": "2023-01-28 17:54:59",
        "name": "John",
        "cart": [
            "Iphone13",
            "Iphone14",
            "Iphone15",
        "Iphone16"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "date": "2023-01-28 18:24:29",
        "name": "Frank",
        "cart": [
            "Android10",
            "Android11"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: use `fetch`  to read the txt

Comment: it's just that I'm having trouble split the name, cart and date

Answer (score 0):

I think the following logic would do it good.

Load and parse each line of txt file to a list of item class.

class item - with date, name, and list of devices.

Then you can check if the name is already there, add the device into the list of devices.

Then you can stringify the class - refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: it's just that I'm having trouble split the name, cart and date

Comment: Using Regex you can extract each info .. for example date can be extracted using - const regex = /\[([\d\-\:.\s]*)\]/gi; let match = regex.exec(line); match[1] will return '2023-01-28 17:54:59'